# How to measure Key Lookups per Second on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, perfmon, performance-tuning

I am working on reducing the amount of transactions doing key lookups on our SQL Servers.

First I want to define a baseline for the normal or tolerable number on that metric and as we constantly have releases in production, then, I want to create an automation based on it that notifies me when it goes south.

The problem that I am having is actually finding the right counter either on [perfmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx) or a SQL DMV to get the data from.

I looked on the obvious object [SQL Server, Access Methods Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177426(v=sql.105).aspx) yet, I could not find a specific one. I also tried other counters or SQL views but could not find it.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of a fully accurate and reliable way to track this.

One way to get at least *something* potentially useful is to keep snapshots of [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms188755.aspx), specifically the `user_lookups` column for index_id 0 (RID Lookup) and 1 (Key Lookup). This DMV can be reset for many reasons, including database or instance restarts. Rebuilding (but not reorganizing) and index also clears the related DMV entry on SQL Server 2012 and later, which can make things more difficult. You will need to capture information fairly regularly and use a heuristic to decide if the DMV reset between captures.

The index usage stats DMV also only returns a count of the number of times a plan containing a Lookup is executed. A plan that contains a single Key Lookup will increment the counter by 1, regardless of the number of lookups actually performed. It will also increment even if the Lookup is not executed at all.

The [sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174281.aspx) DMV records the number of singleton lookups actually performed, but does not distinguish between singleton seeks on the index directly, and those that result from a Key or RID Lookup, so it is not useful for your purpose.

Singleton seeks are another name for Probe Scans as reported by the Access Methods Object. There is no way to distinguish between a 'normal' singleton seek on a unique index, and a singleton seek resulting from a Lookup. This means the Access Methods Probe Scans counter is not useful to you. The AM counters are very noisy anyway, and there's no way to correlate the counters with a particular index.

Answer (score 0):

A good [write-up by Michael J. Swart](http://michaeljswart.com/2011/03/last-word-on-scans/) seems to indicate that a key lookup will count toward the `Probe Scans/sec` counter under the Access methods:

> **Key Lookup** ([Showplan Operator Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190376.aspx))
>
> This operator is also
> known as a bookmark lookup operator. It always counts towards the
> Probe Scans/sec performance counter. It’s interesting that even though
> it gets a single record at a time, this operator is often seen as a
> symptom of poor performance. That’s because the number of executions
> can get big. Many executions can kill the performance of the query. If
> you focus on the performance counters, you’ll notice that each of
> these executions will count towards the Probe Scans performance
> counter.

Although using the performance counter is only going to give you a number. You would still have to dig into the plan cache to find the specific queries that have the key lookup. [Which is possible](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/finding-key-lookups-inside-the-plan-cache/).

**Note**: The link above to the showplan operator is what Michael linked to, but I happened to find the current documentation in MSDN that provides a bit more current information: [Showplan Logical and Physical Operators Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191158.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately non-Lookup singleton seeks into a unique clustered index are also reported as Probe Scans, so this cannot be used to distinguish a Key/RID Lookup from an equality seek into a unique clustered index.